# Android NDK: возврат массива

Tags: android-sdk, jni, c++

В программе на с++ формируются данные, которые требуется передать в java. Данные в виде нескольких объектов `class{ String name; int x, y, sx, sy; };` Можно запрашивать каждое значение отдельной функцией, но это совсем не вариант.

Есть способ, которым можно вернуть в java массив, например в виде списка ключей и значений? Или в виде дерева, куда можно положить сразу все необходимые значения. То есть вопрос: как вернуть значения и пользоваться ими с легкостью и простотой.

UPD. Вот как-то так. http://mikelsv.livejournal.com/8902.html . << Это ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибаться, но в поле можно использовать тип `JNI jobject`, а точнее их массив передавая в функцию `JNI` и потом использовать в Java.

Первое, что пришло в голову.

Comment: В голову может прийти что угодно, вопрос, как это реализовать. :)

В общем я нашел пример и пытаюсь перетащить в свой код. Если я правильно понял, то смогу вернуть целый массив переменных класса, написанного в джаве. Если получится будет офигенно. О лучшем и не мечталось. (конечно кроме варианта писать совсем без джавы).

Comment: Блин, смысл был наследоваться от jobject в С++ и спокойно все передалось бы, если правильно понял вопрос. В чем проблема - не понятно.

Comment: вообще то с jni кода можно модифицировать объекты java. Так что никаких проблем.

Comment: Здесь одна теория, а хотелось практической информации. Вопрос решен.

Comment: @mikelsv, ответьте тогда на свой вопрос здесь же раз вопрос решен.

Comment: @Raskilas, ссылка на ответ в последней строчке вопроса.